# reverse a regexp substitution

Tags: python, regex

Given a string transformation expressed as a regexp substitution, is there a convenient way to reverse that transformation, preferably in python?

For example, given the transformation

```
def f(x): return re.sub('foo((:?bar)?)', r'\1', x)
```

which transforms `'foobar'` to `'bar'` and `'foo'` to the empty string, I would like to obtain

```
def g(x): return re.sub('((:?bar)?)', r'foo\1', x)
```

which does the reverse, in the sense that

```
f(g(x)) == x
```

Obviously not all regexp substitutions are 1:1 mappings, but my wishful thinking is that they can all be reversed in the sense of obtaining one possible input value `g(x)` that would yield a given output `x` from the original substitution.

Why would I want to do this? I'd like to generate URLs for arbitrary filesystem paths based on parsing `AliasMatch` directives in an Apache config file.

Comment: +1 for a very interesting problem, but I doubt there is a comprehensible solution that's even remotely reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't work; `('(bar)?', 'foo$1')` is not the reverse of `('foo(bar)?', '$1')`.

If you try it (dropping the group substitution for the moment):

```
import re
re.sub(r'(bar)?', 'foo', 'xyz')
```

you get `fooxfooyfoozfoo`.

That's because `(bar)?` matches the null string, and the null string exists at every possible location in the string.

I'd suggest that with problems like this in such a simple example, you might want to seek a different approach to whatever you're actually trying to do.

(I dropped the group above because that doesn't actually work in Python.  If you do `re.sub(r'(bar)?', r'foo\1', 'xyz')`, it'll fail with an exception if `(bar)?` was skipped.  You can fix this with `((bar)?)`, so the outer grouping is never omitted.  This is incidental to your problem, though.)

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I've corrected the example as you suggested. Now, passing `'fooxfooyfoozfoo'` into the original substitution gives me back `'xyz'`. Thus, I think `'fooxfooyfoozfoo'` is an acceptable result...

Answer (score 0):

Well, practically what happens in this example is:

```
xy? -> $1
y?  -> x$1
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're after with this - more examples wouldn't hurt - but I think that general formula could be expanded to cover more at least simple cases.

Comment: Yep, that's my feeling too... My question is if a small set of similarly simple rules would in fact cover all possible regexps, and if there's a way to apply such rules that doesn't require me to write my own regexp parser.